Which hash algorithms support binary input of arbitrary bit length?
Background
In theory, hash functions produce a binary number having bounded (often fixed) length from binary data of arbitrary length.
In practice, specifications and implementations constrain the input length to be a multiple of 8.  This is reasonable because, in practice, the binary data that clients hash is represented in chunks of bytes (not bits).
Suppose that we want to use hash algorithms in a context that cannot assume the input binary data is chunked into bytes.

For example, we want to compute a hash for a 13-bit data stream 0101111101111.

Further, assume that the value intended by any binary fragment of a length indivisible by 8 is unambiguously distinct from any padded byte-divisible representation.

For example, our system requires that the 13-bit 0101111101111 means something fundamentally different from any 16-bit value (such as the left-padded 0000101111101111 or right-padded 0101111101111000).  Consequently, their hashes should be distinct.

Question

What established hash algorithms are compatible with input binary data of arbitrary bit length?

What prior work and implementations exist that directly address this limitation of many common algorithms and libraries?


Note
I recognize that the distinction between truncated arbitrary-length binary data and padded byte-chunks could be retrofitted into byte-divisible input by tagging the padded input data with a byte-divisible representation of its truncated length.  If a less redundant approach is available, it would seem preferable.

Hashes are inherently ambiguous, but you want a distinction between a hash from a 16-bit value and one from a 13-bit value, which doesn't even exist between hashes of two arbitrary 16-bit values?

This question is practically relevant to cryptographic hashes.  Various padding schemes are used to ensure that hashes are distinct for messages of any bit length: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Bit_padding. Easy way is just to add a 1 bit at the end and then zero-pad out to the block size.

@500-InternalServerError Actually, 8192 distinct 13-bit values do exist.  The problem is that exactly 0 of the 8192 values are unambiguously representable as a sequence of bytes.

Padding like the one suggested by @MattTimmermans is just a way to add a end-of-message marker to any message.

Hash function definitions for algorithms like md5, sha1, sha256, sha512, rmd160 etc are all capable of hashing an arbitrary number of input bits, up to some high limit. Some others have no upper limit. In practice, almost nobody cares to hash data that is not a multiple of 8 bits, so many implementations only support this. You can code your own implementation easily enough if you need to hash arbitrary bit length inputs.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming. Also, it has been asked on Crypto.SE as well, where it is on-topic.

Do as @MattTimmermans suggested. Add a 1 at the end, then pad to fill out the byte.
Then if you feel that this is wasteful, you can simply truncate the last few bits off of the hash value that you get. You'll increase the odds of random collisions slightly, but it will still be a usable hash.
Specifying the actual computation in terms of bits doesn't make much sense. CPUs have highly optimized operations corresponding to common data types of specific lengths. A good hashing algorithm will take advantage of this. Trying to roll one with bit specific optimizations is a lot of extra work that won't take advantage of the hardcoded optimizations that the chip already has.
